# Increase the number of messages read in a timeframe using google API

Tags: gmail-api

My application needs to read the message id and subject of all the messages in Gmail using Google REST API. I understand that I need to make 2 calls. First call retrieves all the message ids. Then I try to retrieve the subject of the message ids in batch.

Currently I am able to read 3000 messages in 90 seconds (1min and 30 seconds). I want to be able to read more messages in the same timeframe.

Please suggest on how this can be done.

Note: I am already using gzip and partial response. Any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: have you looked into batching requests? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch One caveat is you're limited to 100 calls in a single batch request. If you need to make more calls than that use multiple batch calls.

Answer (score 2):

The Gmail API has a couple of limitations when it comes to [usage](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota):

> Daily Usage:  1,000,000,000 quota units per day
>
> Per User Rate Limit:  250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts)

Listing messages costs 5 quota units, and getting an individual message also costs 5 quota units.
[Listing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) allows us to get 100 message ids in one API call. This gives us 250 / 5 = 50 listing calls per second => 50 * 100 = 5000 message ids per second. Just listing ~3000 messages in quick succession should not make you hit a brick wall, as far as the quota goes.

Ignoring the bursting capabilities of the quota, [getting](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) messages can be done 250 / 5 = 50 messages a second. This would in theory allow us to get 3000 messages in 3000 / 50 = 60 seconds, landing at a little bit more than a minute total.

I have never tried something this quota-intensive before, so I wrote a little experiment for fun using Nodejs, to test how hard you can burst the quota. I made sure to only ask for partial data, and I used batch requests:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var googleUtils = require('google-api-batch-utils');
var createBatchBody = googleUtils.createBatchBody;
var parseBatchResponse = googleUtils.parseBatchResponse;
var _ = require('lodash');

// Boundary used in the batch request, to reduce the number of http requests
// when getting the subject of the messages.
var BOUNDARY = 'example_boundary';
// If the quota should be exceeded, how long should we wait to try again?
var TIMEOUT = 1000;
// Playground access token authorized with the Gmail scopes:
// https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '{API_KEY}';

function listAllMessageIds() {
  var resultingIds = [];

  return (function listMessageIds(pageToken) {
    return rp({
      uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages',
      qs: {
        access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
        pageToken: pageToken,
        fields: 'messages(id),nextPageToken'
      },
      json: true
    }).then(function(response) {
      var messages = response.messages;
      var nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;
      if (messages) {
        resultingIds = resultingIds.concat(_.pluck(messages, 'id'));
      }
      if (nextPageToken) {
        return listMessageIds(nextPageToken);
      } else {
        return resultingIds;
      }
    });
  })(null);
}

function getSubjectOfAllMessages(messageIds) {
  var resultingSubjectIdObjects = [];
  var uris = messageIds.map(function(id) {
    return {
      uri: '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' + id,
      qs: {
        fields: 'id,payload/headers',
        format: 'metadata',
        metadataHeaders: 'subject'
      }
    };
  });
  var idChunks = _.chunk(uris, 100);
 
  return (function getSubjectOfChunk(chunk) {
    if (!chunk) {
      return resultingSubjectIdObjects;
    }
    var batchBody = createBatchBody(chunk, BOUNDARY);
    return rp({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + BOUNDARY + '"'
        },
        body: batchBody
      })
      .then(parseBatchResponse)
      .then(function(messages) {
        resultingSubjectIdObjects =
          resultingSubjectIdObjects.concat(messages.map(function (m) {
            return {id: m.id, subject: _.get(m, 'payload.headers[0].value') || ''};
          }));
        return getSubjectOfChunk(idChunks.shift());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(getSubjectOfChunk(chunk));
          }, TIMEOUT);
        });
      });

  })(idChunks.shift());
}

console.time(1);
listAllMessageIds().then(getSubjectOfAllMessages).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.length + ' messages where fetched in ');
  console.timeEnd(1);
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
// => 7534 messages where fetched in 63277ms
```

With partial responses and batch requests, I could fetch ~7500 messages without trouble in 63 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Besides batch, there's also using multiple threads.  Also, if you only need subject headers make sure you're using `message.get(format=METADATA, metadataHeaders=["subject"])` so you're only requesting the data you need, etc.